# how to make mdi child forms using MDI parent form?

Tags: vb.net

i made 15 form in my project after that i made home form a parent MDI from by giving property isMDIparent true.now i want to make all form as child form of home form but i dont no way to do.so please suggest me code to assign all form to make child form of parentMDI home form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the child Form's [MdiParent Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent.aspx) to your MdiContainer. This example assumes two Forms one named Form1 and the other named Form2. All properties are being set programmatically.

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()
        Me.IsMdiContainer = True
        Dim frm2 As Form2 = New Form2
        frm2.Owner = Me
        frm2.MdiParent = Me
        frm2.Show()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer, straight from Microsoft:

```
Protected Sub MDIChildNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuItem2.Click
   Dim NewMDIChild As New Form2()
   'Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
   NewMDIChild.MdiParent = Me
   'Display the new form.
   NewMDIChild.Show()
End Sub
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7aw8zc76(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think Mr.Mark Hall missed 1 property.., 
Try this.......

```
Public Class Form1

Public Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()
    Me.IsMdiContainer = True
    Dim frm2 As Form2 = New Form2
    frm2.Owner = Me
    frm2.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
    frm2.Show()

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

it is actualy this:

```
Private sub new()

Dim c as form1 = new form1
c.owner = Me
c.MdiParent = Me
c.show

End sub
```

`InitializeComponent()` does just what it says, it initializes a component. It is NOT for `Mdichild`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub HomeToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   Dim homechild As New login
   homechild.MdiParent = Me
   homechild.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
   homechild.Show()
End Sub
```

Try This Guys..Here Is the Code To Open A Form As MDI Child for an MDI Parent From in vb.net.