# minimize vb.net forms to mdiparent bottom eg. adobe photoshop

Tags: vb.net, minimize, childwindow

vb.net 2008

I have 1 mdiparent and many child forms. on clicking minimize button of child form it should minimize and display at the botton of mdiparent and not in taskbar. like in adobe photoshop. Is it possible to do? if yes how?

Comment: No one to help on this issue !!!

Comment: This behavior is provided by default provided you actually set MdiParent property of the child form.

Comment: Ciaran Thanks ..I wasnt knowing this..and have posted solution for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the child Form's MdiParent Property to your MdiContainer. This example assumes two Forms one named Form1 and the other named Form2. All properties are being set programmatically.

Public Class Form1

```
Public Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()
    Me.IsMdiContainer = True
    Dim frm2 As Form2 = New Form2
    frm2.Owner = Me
    frm2.MdiParent = Me
    frm2.Show()

End Sub
```

Refer: [how to make mdi child forms using MDI parent form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867357/how-to-make-mdi-child-forms-using-mdi-parent-form)